# How to get field with ForeignKey('self') without the possibility to link to same entry?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I came in touch with a little problem while building a model with a foreign key to itself.

Here an example:

```
class Example (model.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)
    # and some other fields
```

After creating a new entry in the admin panel and going into this example for editing some content, I realize that I could set the parent to the current entry. But thats not what I wanted to get with the ForeignKey and the relation to itself.

**Is it possible to disallow the link to itself?**

Maybe it's better to use a integer field with the right choices but I'm not quiet sure how to realize this an a smooth and Python like way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way to do this would be to override the model's clean method

```
class Example(model.Model):
    #...
    def clean(self):
        if self.parent.id == self.id:
            raise ValidationError("no self referential models")
```

this will be called as the second step of object validation and will prevent the object from being inserted in the database.

Comment: Yes, that's the way to go. It is explained in the Model Validation section of the doc: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects

Comment: Thats a bit awesome! :) Thank you for this.

Comment: Another question to this topic: Is it possible to assign this error to a specific field? And in addition to this to disable the option from the select in the admin panel? The typical cosmetic surgery. ;)

Comment: @Lemmi assuming that this is for the admin, I would use [this technique](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-custom-validation-to-the-admin)

Comment: For everyone looking for a solution deleting the choice for self refercing in the ForeignKey ... http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to disallow a link from an instance to the same instance. One way to achieve this would be to add a custom [model validation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#validating-objects). For e.g.

```
class Example(models.Model):
    ...
    def clean_fields(self):
        if self.id and self.parent.id == self.id:
            raise ValidationError(...)
```